# Best way to deploy subversion (SVN) in a multisite windows environment

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

We are planning on moving for MS Source Safe (ouch) to SVN. We are working mostly in a Microsoft environment (windows, Visual Studio, .NET) and we have developers in multiple sites. I heard about VisualSVN and integration with visual studio. On the other hand I can get someone to host SVN for me and use TortoiseSVN. Any recommendations? Any pitfalls I should avoid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hosting subversion is fantastically simple.  At the risk of being labeled a brown nose (is there a badge for that?) Jeff Atwood did put up an article on installing subersion

- http://blog.codinghorror.com/setting-up-subversion-on-windows/

So really you could save yourself some money by running your own subversion server and you'll never have to worry about what happens to your code if your hosting company goes belly up.

I would start with tortoise because it is free and is really easy to use.  If you find you really need integration with VS then by all means try out visual svn.  In my experience source control <-> editor integration is most useful for automatically opening files when you edit them.  Subversion doesn't require you to open files so that big advantage is gone.

Answer (score 5):

> I heard about VisualSVN and
>   integration with visual studio

Point to note, VisualSVN (the one that integrates with VStudio) is *not* a server technology at all, it is simply a integrated GUI front end to SVN, and in fact works *through* TortoiseSVN (which is **required** to be installed).  However, VisualSVN is GREAT and defnitely worth the $50 per developer to use it.  I used it daily and it saves me SO much time.

There is also VisualSVN Server, which will take care of the server side of things and the setup is absolutely dead simple.  As long as you have an internet facing server and copious amounts of bandwidth (though SVN is not much of a bandwidth hog) you should be fine to host it yourself.  Oh yeah, and VisualSVN *Server* is completely FREE!

However, having your repository hosted off-site is definitely always an option.
I use dreamhost for this now and couldn't be happier.

Answer (score 2):

Another SVN integration with Visual studio is AnkhSVN http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/  It is free, and has a few quirks.  Personally, I use it for basic diffing and the visual indicators for file status (changed, conflict, etc.) while I use Tortoise for the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

You can get hosting of secure svn repositories from a variety of sources: http://beanstalkapp.com/ and many others. Often free if the usage (users, data, etc.) is limited.

VisualSVN does integrate with Visual Studio but not like SourceSafe does (and I mean this in a good way). It requires TortoiseSVN so it's not not an either/or. VisualSVN and Tortoise is a great combination.

Answer (score 1):

> Best way to deploy subversion (SVN) in a multisite windows environment

As far as I understand, you have multiple development teams in different locations (even different continents, maybe) who have to access the same codebase. For such a case VisualSVN Server provides [**Multisite Repository Replication** feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/).

The feature is based on VDFS (VisualSVN Distributed File System) technology which allows automatic, transparent, bidirectional master/slave replication of your repositories between remote sites. What's more -- it works out-of-the-box with minimal configuration steps done via VisualSVN Server Manager MMC console.

Learn more at http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00068/